# How to covert an array of Object into Object with key and value as array

Tags: javascript

I m looking for optimized solution using reddduced function to covert array of object to an object with values as an array

```js
const companies=[
    {name:'Company One',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'X Name',email:'grfgr@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'A one',email:'grfgt@yahoo.com',phone:'943548213', category:'Lecture',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:' Name',email:'gtrgt@gmail.com',phone:'9656013653', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003},
    {name:'Company Name',email:'grgtrgg@gmail.com', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'sdksdjd',email:'bfbrg@gbmail.com',phone:'7485788475898548', category:'Sciennce',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'kdjfkf',email:'gfggfb@gmail.com',phone:'0959898860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjf',email:'g5rgf@gmail.com',phone:'050498860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjvk',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'958958860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdkv',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'5434886013821543543', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'zeeshan',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8864535213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'}
]

// Looking for better and optimised solution to convert array of object into object with.  values as an array using map methods  

let reduced_object={}

let reduced_array=companies.reduce((arr,current)=>{

let entries=Object.entries(current)

entries.forEach(element=>{

    if(reduced_object.hasOwnProperty(element[0])){
       reduced_object[element[0]].push(element[1])

    }else{
    reduced_object[element[0]]=[element[1]];

    }
})

return reduced_object
})

console.log(reduced_array)
```

Comment: You can try this `companies.reduce((r, o) => {
      Object.entries(o).forEach(([k,v]) => (r[k] ??= []).push(v));
      return r;
    }, {})`. It is similar to your solution in performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simple `forEach` loops, iterate and check for each item.

```js
const process = (arr, output = {}) => {
  arr.forEach((obj) =>
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      (output[key] ||= []).push(value)
    )
  );
  return output;
};

const companies=[
    {name:'Company One',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'X Name',email:'grfgr@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'A one',email:'grfgt@yahoo.com',phone:'943548213', category:'Lecture',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:' Name',email:'gtrgt@gmail.com',phone:'9656013653', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003},
    {name:'Company Name',email:'grgtrgg@gmail.com', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'sdksdjd',email:'bfbrg@gbmail.com',phone:'7485788475898548', category:'Sciennce',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'kdjfkf',email:'gfggfb@gmail.com',phone:'0959898860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjf',email:'g5rgf@gmail.com',phone:'050498860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjvk',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'958958860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdkv',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'5434886013821543543', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'zeeshan',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8864535213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'}
]


console.log(process(companies))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not use reducing:

```
let obj = {
  name: companies.map(item => item.name).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  email: companies.map(item => item.email).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  phone: companies.map(item => item.phone).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  category: companies.map(item => item.category).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  start: companies.map(item => item.start).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  end: companies.map(item => item.end).filter(value => value !== undefined),
  date: companies.map(item => item.date).filter(value => value !== undefined)
}
```

Edit: Added filters to remove 'undefined' entries when properties are missing in the source.

Comment: But object keys could be variable ,if keys does not exists then it will put undefined

Comment: 1. You should have mentioned that in your post. 2. You edited your post and deleted the phone entry on the line starting with **{name:'Company Name', ...** – you should have mentioned that to!

Comment: my bad but  the real scenerio is that object keys could be a variable,and not fix for all entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use map instead:

```js
// ...
const reduced_object = {};
reduced_object.name = companies.map(item => item.name);
reduced_object.email = companies.map(item => item.email);
reduced_object.phone = companies.map(item => item.phone);
// ...
```

Of course, once you know (or determine) the list of keys of each item, you can wrap it up in a for-of loop:

```js
// ...
const reduced_object = {};
for (let key of item_keys) {
    reduced_object[key] = companies.map(item => item[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```js
const companies=[
    {name:'Company One',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'X Name',email:'grfgr@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'A one',email:'grfgt@yahoo.com',phone:'943548213', category:'Lecture',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:' Name',email:'gtrgt@gmail.com',phone:'9656013653', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'Company Name',email:'grgtrgg@gmail.com',phone:'954543656138256', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'sdksdjd',email:'bfbrg@gbmail.com',phone:'7485788475898548', category:'Sciennce',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'kdjfkf',email:'gfggfb@gmail.com',phone:'0959898860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjf',email:'g5rgf@gmail.com',phone:'050498860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjvk',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'958958860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdkv',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'5434886013821543543', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'zeeshan',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8864535213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'}
]

const arr = companies.reduce((acc, company) => ({
    ...acc,
    ...Object.entries(company).reduce((objAcc, [key, val]) => ({
      ...objAcc,
      [key]: [...acc?.[key] ?? [], ...val ? [val] : []]
    }), {})
}), {})

console.log(arr)
```

If you don't want to have duplicate values you can also do this:

```js
const companies=[
    {name:'Company One',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'X Name',email:'grfgr@gmail.com',phone:'8860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'A one',email:'grfgt@yahoo.com',phone:'943548213', category:'Lecture',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:' Name',email:'gtrgt@gmail.com',phone:'9656013653', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'Company Name',email:'grgtrgg@gmail.com',phone:'954543656138256', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'sdksdjd',email:'bfbrg@gbmail.com',phone:'7485788475898548', category:'Sciennce',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'kdjfkf',email:'gfggfb@gmail.com',phone:'0959898860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjf',email:'g5rgf@gmail.com',phone:'050498860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdjvk',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'958958860138213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'vdkv',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'5434886013821543543', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'},
    {name:'zeeshan',email:'trishabh885@gmail.com',phone:'8864535213', category:'Finance',start:1981,end:2003,date:'21-06-2009'}
]

const arr = companies.reduce((acc, company) => ({
    ...acc,
    ...Object.entries(company).reduce((objAcc, [key, val]) => ({
      ...objAcc,
      [key]: [...new Set([...acc?.[key] ?? [], ...val ? [val] : []])]
    }), {})
}), {})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fun functional route:

```
[...new Set(companies.flatMap(Object.keys))]
    .reduce((result, key) => {result[key] = companies.map(c => c[key]); return result;}, {})
```

The first line finds all the keys. The second line creates the desired result. But honestly, in real life, I would skip that reduce and write a simple for loop. I would always pick clarity over "functional purity".